# How to make predictions on genes not involved in a particular disease

Tags: molecular-biology, bioinformatics

I have one set of genes which counts about 100 such that every gene of that set is evidence based involved in a particular disease. Let's call this set A. For a machine learning project I need a set of genes that is with high probability not involved in that particular disease. Let's call this set B. Usually in science one focuses on finding a gene that is involved in a pathology and not the opposite,i.e. finding a gene that is not involved in that particular pathology. But one can eventually make predictions based on some strategy in creating the set B. Knowing the genes of set A in terms of their identity, location in the genome, expression profile in a certain tissue where the pathology arises etc., how could one propose the set B ? Can one indicate a paper or present his/her own experience with a similar question ?

Many thanks.

Comment: Simple idea: find a GWAS for the trait you’re interested in, aggregate p values across genes and take a random set of the genes with the lowest highest p-value

Comment: Thanks. The set A is not based on GWAS. It is difficult to find GWAS studies in this case.